# python counting words in JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying use python to count the words length in a specific key in a JSON file but i am stuck with it, please help me !

the desired output should be couting the words length for each sentence it should output:

> 131
>
> 121
>
> 150

something like above.

Comment: What do you mean by "counting the word length for each sentence"? I have no idea what you are trying to do from reading this. Also, `len(str(names).split())` is turning a list into a string and back into a list, which I hope you can see by that description is totally pointless.

Comment: what will be output??

Comment: @VivekSable i have edited the output could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple loop:

```
for item in names:
    print len(item.split())
```